# Как получить элемент текущего узла html с помощью Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я делаю ajax запрос и получаю в ответ хтмл, мне нужно взять по айдишнику или классу содержимое узла 1 ранга. то есть вот такой хтмл получаю:

```
<div class='download-file'>
    <a class="btn btn-primary download-file" data-method="POST" href="foo/bar">Download File</a>
    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-3x update"></i>
</div>
```

нужно значение узла `download-file`, он не дочерний. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне получить этот узел? `$(resp).???` что тут написать?

Comment: Не дочерний это как? Он где-то рядом лежит или что?

Comment: "узла 1 ранга" - ??

Comment: @Igor @Telion узла 1 ранга - это так, что ты получаешь html, как у меня в примере показано. Этот хтмл хранится в одной переменной, как получить доступ к самому первому элементу в этой иерархии? в этом мне помог `.filter(".download-file")`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам поможет `find()`:

```
$(resp).find(".download-file");
```

Comment: не поможет. помогло `.filter(".download-file")`